# D3 arrow markers

Tags: d3.js, marker

Good afternoon. This scripr load a file and representing it this d3 code. So I need to change the marker I want to add a direccional arrow althought when I add the attr for that nothing happen. Anyone can suggest me something.

Changing the viewBox attribute so that the second vector is not works for me even you suggest me.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <meta name="keywords" content="Cluster comparison, partition agreement, microbial typing, typing methods" />
      <meta name="author" content="Rui Oliveira" />
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" media="screen" /> -->
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
           <title>Adjusted Rand diagram</title>

        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.geom.js?1.29.1"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?1.29.1"></script>

    <style type="text/css">


    h2{
    background: #EBF0F3;
    font: normal 1.2em Tahoma, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    color: #114054;
    }

    p {
    text-align:center; 
    padding-top:40px;
    font: normal 0.9em Tahoma, sans-serif;
    }


    path.link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #666;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    marker {
      fill: #666;
    }

    marker#strong {
      fill: black;
    }


    path.link.strong {
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    path.link.weak {
      stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
    }

    circle {
      fill: #ccc;
      stroke: #333;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    text {
      font: 14px sans-serif;
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    text.shadow {
      stroke: #fff; 
      style="text-align:center; display"
      stroke-width: 3px;
      stroke-opacity: .8;
    }

    line {
    stroke-opacity: 10;
    }

        </style>
      </head>

      <body style="text-align:center;display"> 



      <h2> Adjusted Rand</h2>

      <!--[if IE]>
      <p>Warning:</p>
      <p>Internet Explorer does not allow you to visualize this diagram. Please use a browser that supports svg. We recommend you to use <a href="http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/">Firefox</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/">Google Chrome</a> as alternative.</p>
    <![endif]-->

        <script type="text/javascript">

    // http://blog.thomsonreuters.com/index.php/mobile-patent-mediums-graphic-of-the-day/


    var links = [<?php
    $b='karateP1000T005.npf';
    if(file_exists($b))
        $a = fopen($b, "r");
    else{
        echo "]
        alert('Invalid file!');</script></body></html>";
        exit(0);
    }
    $nodes=$links=array();

        while (!feof($a) ) {

        $l = urlencode(fgets($a));
        $l=explode('%09',$l);
          if(count($l)==2)
              $nodes[]=$l;
          else if(count($l)==3){
              $links[]=$l;
              echo '{source: "',(int) $l['0'],'", target: "',(int) $l['1'],'", type: "medium", value: "',(int) $l['2'],'"},';
          }

        }

        fclose($a);

    ?>

      ];

    var nodes = {};

    //Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
    });

    var w = window.innerWidth, //1100
    h = window.innerHeight;   //1690

    var force = d3.layout.force()
     .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
     .links(links)

    //defines where to center the graph
     .size([w, h])
     .linkDistance(150)
     .charge(-1000)
     .on("tick", tick)
     .start();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
      // defines the canvas size
      .attr("width", w)
             .attr("height", h);

    svg.append("svg:line").
          attr("x1", 10).
          attr("y1", 10 ).
          attr("x2", 60 ).
          attr("y2", 10).
          attr("stroke", "black").
          attr("stroke-width", "2.5px");

    svg.append("svg:line").
        attr("stroke", "black").
          attr("x1", 10).
          attr("y1", 30 ).
          attr("x2", 60 ).
          attr("y2", 30);

    svg.append("svg:line").
        attr("stroke", "black").
          attr("x1", 10).
          attr("y1", 50 ).
          attr("x2", 60 ).
          attr("y2", 50).
          attr("stroke-dasharray", "0,2 1");

    svg.append("svg:text").
        attr("x", 65).
        attr("y", 10).
        text("[0.90,1]")

    svg.append("svg:text").
        attr("x", 65).
        attr("y", 30).
        text("[0.75,0.90[")

    svg.append("svg:text").
        attr("x", 65).
        attr("y", 50).
        text("]0.60,0.75[")

    //Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
     .data(["medium"])
    .enter().append("svg:marker")
     .attr("id", String)
     .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
     .attr("refX", 20)
     .attr("refY", -1.5)
     .attr("markerWidth", 6)
     .attr("markerHeight", 6)
     .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("svg:path")
     .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    // add the links and the arrows
    var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
     .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("svg:path")
     .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
     .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

    var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
     .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("svg:circle")
     .attr("r", 20)
     .call(force.drag);

    var text = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
     .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("svg:g");

    //A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
    text.append("svg:text")
     .attr("x", 8)
     .attr("y", ".31em")
     .attr("class", "shadow")
     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    text.append("svg:text")
     .attr("x", 8)
     .attr("y", ".31em")
     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    //Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
    function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
     var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x ,
         dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
              dr=0;
              //dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      return "M" + 
        d.source.x + "," + 
        d.source.y + "A" + 
        dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
        d.target.x + "," +
        d.target.y;

    });

    circle.attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    text.attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
    }

    </script>


    <textarea rows="2" cols="50" style="position:fixed; top:0px;right:0px;" autofocus="true" >
    <<?php echo $b; ?>
    </textarea>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Why did you mark your previous question as answered if the answer didn't solve your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [D3 arrow marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316323/d3-arrow-marker)